# csh inline if statements

Tags: if-statement, csh, tcsh

I'm trying to add a script to check conditions before executing a command in my `.cshrc` file. This checker script returns 0 if the conditions are insufficient, and 1 otherwise. (I realize this is backwards of convention, but I thought it would be easier for if statements.)

Here is what I've tried, replacing the command with `echo "ok"`:

```
./checker.sh && echo "ok"
```

Echoes "ok" even though `checker.sh` returns 0.

```
test ./checker.sh && echo "ok"
```

Echoes "ok" even though `checker.sh` returns 0, but also suppresses error messages in `checker.sh`.

```
if ( ./checker.sh ) then echo "ok" endif
```

Throws an if-statement syntax error.

I want to turn this into an alias, hence the one-line constraint, e.g.

```
alias doAction './checker.sh && echo "ok"'
```

How does one accomplish this with `(t)csh` without directly calling the command in the checker script?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to execute the code on nonzero exit do `checker.csh || echo "ok"`

Comment: To avoid the syntax error for single line `if` statements in `csh` do not use `then` and `endif`. For example: `if ( 1 ) echo "y"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the script to `exit 0` when there is NO problem, and exit a nonzero number when there is a problem. Then

```
./checker.sh && echo "ok"
```

behaves as desired...

Note to others who may read this: the above "test" construct is not equivalent to the C-style if-statement

```
if(./checker.sh){
  echo "ok"
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging apparently also applies to posting questions on stackoverflow...